# Is the composition of two "pure" inner automorphisms of a Lie algebra a pure inner automorphism?

Tags: lie-algebras, automorphism-group

Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and an ad-nipotent element $x$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, it can be shown that $\exp(\operatorname{ad} x)$ is a Lie algebra automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$. Its inverse can be computed to be $\exp(-\operatorname{ad} x)$. Let us call an automorphism of this form a "pure inner automorphism". Note that the identity on $\mathfrak{g}$ writes as a pure inner automorphism, $\exp(\operatorname{ad}0)=1_\mathfrak{g}$. My question is: is the composition of two pure inner automorphism a pure inner automorphism? I was thinking that perhaps the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula could generalize to this situation. If given ad-nilpotent elements $x,y\in\mathfrak{g}$ one were to look for an ad-nipotent element $z$ that solved the equation
$$\exp(\operatorname{ad} x)\exp(\operatorname{ad} y)=\exp(\operatorname{ad} z),$$
I guess the sum of the iterated Lie brackets from the BCH should turn out to be finite, as $x$ and $y$ are ad-nilpotent, and maybe $z$ could be computed that way, using the fact that $\operatorname{ad}$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism (and assuming that "the bracket of ad-nilpotents elements is ad-nilpotent" is true, which I don't know to be that way).

Typically, in the literature one sees that they define the "subgroup of inner automorphisms," $\operatorname{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})\subset\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$, to be the subgroup *generated* by the pure inner automorphisms. So my question is equivalent to: is the condition *generated by* strictly necessary? The family of pure inner automorphisms isn't in general a subgroup by itself?

Comment: This is true for $G$ complex semisimple and a quick search suggests it is true more generally for semisimple groups without compact factors and with only 1 conjugacy class of Cartan subgroups. I'm not sure that it is always true beyond those. Certainly, it is not true that $x$ and $y$ ad-nilpotent forces the BCH series to terminate: consider taking them in opposite root spaces for example.

Comment: In compact real semisimple LAs, there are no non-trivial nilpotent elements, so the answer is trivially yes. But note that one could consider the group of those automorphisms which become a product of elementary ones after scalar extension; this one, then would obviously be bigger than those that are elementary or generated by elementary ones. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3178915/96384

Comment: @Callum: Do you have a quick argument or reference as to why this is true in the cases you mention?

Comment: [Here you go](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01765631.pdf) In fact, looking at it again, they also prove it is true in a few other cases as well

Comment: @Callum Thanks. From that article, and a little browsing around, my first place to look for an explicit counterexample would be (the elementary automorphisms of) $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb R)$. I doubt I would have time and skill to come up with something in the next while though. Do you?

Comment: @Torsten I may be mistaken on this but the projective span of $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&1\\ 0&0&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ in $PSL(4,\mathbb{R})$ seems to be a counterexample. My motivation for this is the usual counterexample for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ in two blocks but twisted so that multiplication by $-1$ swaps which block is not an exponential so that it should still work in the projective group. The proof would go roughly like the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348699/showing-that-the-exponential-map-mathrmexp-mathfraksl2-mathbbr-to-ma)